# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(1-x)^{1/3}-(1+x)^{1/2}}{x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Evaluate the limit
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(1-x)^{1/3}-(1+x)^{1/2}}{x}$$
I know the limit is $-5\over6$ by looking at the graph of the function, but how can I algebraically show that that is the limit?

Comment: It appears that your limit is [incorrect](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+x+to+0+[%281-x%29^%281%2F3%29-%281-x%29^%281%2F2%29]%2Fx)

Comment: @DanielLittlewood There is a $+$ under the the square root, not a minus. So the OP's correct..

Comment: Stupid mistake on my part! Sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

or simply 
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(1-x)^{1/3}+1-1-(1+x)^{1/2}}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}-\frac{(1-x)^{1/3}-1}{-x}-\frac{(1+x)^{1/2}-1}{x}=-\frac{5}{6}
$$

Comment: How do you do your last step? You have $\frac00 - \frac00$... You need to explain you taking derivatives

Comment: you must use the limit $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{(1-x)^{\alpha}-1}{x}= \alpha$

Comment: does it (limit) have a name?

Comment: the correct form of the limit is $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{(1+x)^c -1}{x} =c$. The general form is $\lim_{f(x) \rightarrow 0} \frac{(1+f(x))^c -1}{f(x)} =c$ with $c \in \mathbb{R}$. I don't know if it has a name.

Comment: ok. so how to prove this??? is it possible without L'Hopital Rule?

Comment: You can prove it as exercise. Post your proof.

Comment: I tried. I could not do it. So I post previous 2 comments. Could you help me?

Comment: I know how to do this for c=1/2 but have no idea how to do this for c=1/3

Comment: You must start from the Neperian limit $\left ( 1+\frac{1}{x} \right )^x \underset{x \rightarrow 0}{\rightarrow} e$ (this isn't obvious to prove). Then by some change of variables and passing to logarithms you obtain $\frac{\log(1+x)}{x} \underset{x \rightarrow 0}{\rightarrow} 1$ and finally trought the change of variables $t=(1+x)^c-1$, passing to logarithms and using the related limit you obtain the result.

Comment: in the first limit of course $x \rightarrow +\infty$ or $-\infty$

Answer (score 3):

One method here is to use L'Hopital's rule.  We know that $(1-x)^{1/3}-(1+x)^{1/2}$ and $x$ tend to $0$ as $x\to0$; so,
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(1-x)^{1/3}-(1+x)^{1/2}}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac{d}{dx}\left[(1-x)^{1/3}-(1+x)^{1/2}\right]}{\frac{d}{dx}[x]}
$$
(because this last limit exists, of course!).

Alternatively, you can solve this using the definition of the derivative.  Let $f(x)=(1-x)^{1/3}$ and $g(x)=(1+x)^{1/2}$. Then adding/subtracting $1$ in the numerator yields
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{(1-x)^{1/3}-(1+x)^{1/2}}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\left[\frac{(1-x)^{1/3}-1}{x-0}-\frac{(1+x)^{1/2}-1}{x-0}\right].
$$
But, if you look at it, we've just written
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\left[\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}-\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x-0}\right]=f'(0)-g'(0).
$$

Comment: what about to dont use L'Hopital Rule. Is it possible?

Comment: @DimaRailguner I added another approach; see what you think!

Answer (score 3):

Using the binomial expansions,
$$(1-x)^{1/3}=1-\frac{1}{3}x+O(x^{2}) \mbox{  and  } (1+x)^{1/2}=1+\frac{1}{2}x+O(x^{2})$$
So your expression is simply $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\frac{-5}{6}x+O(x^{2})}{x} = -5/6$$

Comment: $(1+x)^{1/2}$, not $(1-x)^{1/2}$. But good!

Comment: Ah, sorry! I'll correct it

Answer (score 0):

Use L'Hopital's rule (both numerator and denominator go to zero).